# Show that the matrix $A^2 + I$ is invertible for all matrices $A$, where $A$ is an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm a little stuck on this problem. I know that since $A$ is symmetric, $A=A^{T}$. I'm also pretty sure that $AA^{T}$ is invertible. Therefore $A^2$ would be invertible. I'm not really sure how to account for the identity matrix (In).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general $AA^T$ will not be invertible, for example if $A$ is the 0 matrix.  Is this a problem condition?

Comment: No, not a problem condition.  My mistake.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For an arbitrary real valued matrix $A$, $A^TA$ is [positive-semidefinite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Negative-definite.2C_semidefinite_and_indefinite_matrices), so all its eigenvalues are nonnegative. It follows that all the eigenvalues of $A^TA+I$ are no less than $1$, so $A^TA+I$ is invertible(and [positive definite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix)). In particular, when $A$ is symmetric, $A^2+I$ is invertible(and positive definite).

A more direct way is to show that for any nonzero column vector $v$, $(A^TA+I)v\ne 0$. To see this, note that for every column vector $w$, $w^Tw\ge 0$ and the equality holds if and only if $w=0$. Then 
$$v^T(A^TA+I)v=(Av)^T(Av)+v^Tv>0.\tag{1}$$
$(1)$ implies that $(A^TA+I)v\ne 0$, which completes the proof. In fact, $(1)$ also shows that $A^TA+I$ is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks Giraffe!  Would it also work to prove that A^2 + I has no 0 eigenvalues and is thus invertible by the Spectral Theorem?

Comment: @BobbyLupo: You are welcome! Yes, your idea is right, and I updated my answer by showing that $A^2+I$ has no $0$ eigenvalue directly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $A$ is a symmetric matrix, its eigen value are real ( it can be zero as well ) however when the identity matrix is added, the eigen value will become non-zero real values.

Answer (score 1):

## Problem

Show that the matrix *A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* is invertible for all matrices *A*, where *A* is an n×n symmetric matrix.

## Solution

Show that in another basis *A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* is a diagonal matrix with no zeros in the diagonal — in other words, it only scales up or reflects as a transformation, and is thus invertible.

### In Great Detail

The spectral theorem states that if  *A* is symmetric, there exists an invertible *C* matrix and a real diagonal matrix *B* such that *A* = *CBC*<sup>-1</sup>. A diagonal matrix only has values or zeros in the diagonal. (More info: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix)) That conversion is just between bases. (More info: [Khan Academy](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate_bases/change_of_basis/v/linear-algebra--coordinates-with-respect-to-a-basis))

So if we substitute in that *CBC<sup>-1</sup>* for *A*...

*A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub> = (CBC<sup>-1</sup>)<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>
 = CBC<sup>-1</sup>CBC<sup>-1</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>*

But we also know that *I<sub>n</sub> = C<sup>-1</sup>C = CC<sup>-1</sup>*, so we can change that last bit up a bit...

*CBC<sup>-1</sup>CBC<sup>-1</sup> + I<sub>n</sub> = CB I<sub>n</sub> BC<sup>-1</sup> + CC<sup>-1</sup> = CBBC<sup>-1</sup> + CC<sup>-1</sup> = CB<sup>2</sup>C<sup>-1</sup> + CC<sup>-1</sup>*

Matrix multiplication isn't commutative (xy=yx) but it is associative ((xy)z=x(yz)) and distributive (x(y+z)=xy+xz, (y+z)x=yx+zx), so we can change that into another form.

*CB<sup>2</sup>C<sup>-1</sup> + CC<sup>-1</sup> = C(B<sup>2</sup>C<sup>-1</sup> + C<sup>-1</sup>) = C((B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>)C<sup>-1</sup>) = C(B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>)C<sup>-1</sup>*

Why is this important? Well, don't forget that *B* was a *diagonal* matrix!  *B<sup>2</sup>* is going to have positive numbers down the diagonal or zeroes. Since we add the identity matrix *I<sub>n</sub>*, we know that every diagonal entry will have a value of at least 1 (a non-zero value).

So, this shows that *A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* can be expressed as a diagonal matrix of the form *B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* in another basis where all the diagonal entries are equal to or greater than 1.

What does invertible mean? It means you can undo a transformation by multiplying by another matrix. *B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* is a diagonal matrix with no zeros, so each component of a vector mutliplied by *B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* is going to be scaled up in some way or another. In other words, the transformed vector will be only scaled up/down or reflected — in other words, *B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* is a transformation that can be undone. It's invertible.

Well, that doesn't tell us about *A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>*, you might say. But wait! *B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* is just another form of *A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* in another basis. You can convert transformations between bases but still have it be the same transformation. Thus, (*B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>*)'s inverse can be converted back into (*A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>*)'s coordinates. That's the same transformation but in different bases. (*B<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>*)'s inverse is (*A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>*)'s inverse.

Thus, we conclude that *A<sup>2</sup> + I<sub>n</sub>* has an inverse. It is therefore invertible.

Answer (score 0):

Eigenvalues of symmetric matrix are purely real, Enough to show $\det(A^2+I)\ne 0$ i.e enough to show that $-1$ is not an eigen value of $A^2$, $A$ symmetric so if $\lambda_i$'s are eigen values  then $\lambda_i\in\mathbb{R}\forall i$ and the eigen values of $A^2$ will be $\lambda_i^2\ge 0$ so indeed $-1$ can not be an eigen value of $A^2$